# Merging the lazyload plugin jquery code inside my own jquery file

Tags: jquery

Hope you will not laugh but I want to know if I can do this:

I have a normal js file which has several functions and looks like this: (I have listed just one function to keep the code short)

```
function traffic(){
    var ANCHOR = $("ul.trf").data('anchor'); 
    var i = 0;
    $('ul.trf li a').each(function() { 
        var $this = $(this); 
        if ($this.text() === ANCHOR) { 
            i++;
            if(i < 10){
                $this.html(''+ANCHOR+' 0'+i+''); 
            }
            else{
                $this.html(''+ANCHOR+' '+i+'');
            }
        } 
    }); 
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($){      
    noborder(); // Removes The Last li Border
    menu_border(); // Ads Borders to Menu on index.php
    gallery();
    traffic();
});
```

**I also have a second jquery file with the lazyload plugin code:**

(this is the minimal version)

```
(function(a,b){var c=a(b);a.fn.lazyload=function(d){function h(){var b=0;e.each(function(){var c=a(this);if(g.skip_invisible&&!c.is(":visible"))return;if(!a.abovethetop(this,g)&&!a.leftofbegin(this,g))if(!a.belowthefold(this,g)&&!a.rightoffold(this,g))c.trigger("appear");else if(++b>g.failure_limit)return!1})}var e=this,f,g={threshold:0,failure_limit:0,event:"scroll",effect:"show",container:b,data_attribute:"original",skip_invisible:!0,appear:null,load:null};return d&&(undefined!==d.failurelimit&&(d.failure_limit=d.failurelimit,delete d.failurelimit),undefined!==d.effectspeed&&(d.effect_speed=d.effectspeed,delete d.effectspeed),a.extend(g,d)),f=g.container===undefined||g.container===b?c:a(g.container),0===g.event.indexOf("scroll")&&f.bind(g.event,function(a){return h()}),this.each(function(){var b=this,c=a(b);b.loaded=!1,c.one("appear",function(){if(!this.loaded){if(g.appear){var d=e.length;g.appear.call(b,d,g)}a("<img />").bind("load",function(){c.hide().attr("src",c.data(g.data_attribute))[g.effect](g.effect_speed),b.loaded=!0;var d=a.grep(e,function(a){return!a.loaded});e=a(d);if(g.load){var f=e.length;g.load.call(b,f,g)}}).attr("src",c.data(g.data_attribute))}}),0!==g.event.indexOf("scroll")&&c.bind(g.event,function(a){b.loaded||c.trigger("appear")})}),c.bind("resize",function(a){h()}),h(),this},a.belowthefold=function(d,e){var f;return e.container===undefined||e.container===b?f=c.height()+c.scrollTop():f=a(e.container).offset().top+a(e.container).height(),f<=a(d).offset().top-e.threshold},a.rightoffold=function(d,e){var f;return e.container===undefined||e.container===b?f=c.width()+c.scrollLeft():f=a(e.container).offset().left+a(e.container).width(),f<=a(d).offset().left-e.threshold},a.abovethetop=function(d,e){var f;return e.container===undefined||e.container===b?f=c.scrollTop():f=a(e.container).offset().top,f>=a(d).offset().top+e.threshold+a(d).height()},a.leftofbegin=function(d,e){var f;return e.container===undefined||e.container===b?f=c.scrollLeft():f=a(e.container).offset().left,f>=a(d).offset().left+e.threshold+a(d).width()},a.inviewport=function(b,c){return!a.rightofscreen(b,c)&&!a.leftofscreen(b,c)&&!a.belowthefold(b,c)&&!a.abovethetop(b,c)},a.extend(a.expr[":"],{"below-the-fold":function(b){return a.belowthefold(b,{threshold:0})},"above-the-top":function(b){return!a.belowthefold(b,{threshold:0})},"right-of-screen":function(b){return a.rightoffold(b,{threshold:0})},"left-of-screen":function(b){return!a.rightoffold(b,{threshold:0})},"in-viewport":function(b){return!a.inviewport(b,{threshold:0})},"above-the-fold":function(b){return!a.belowthefold(b,{threshold:0})},"right-of-fold":function(b){return a.rightoffold(b,{threshold:0})},"left-of-fold":function(b){return!a.rightoffold(b,{threshold:0})}})})(jQuery,window)
```

Is there a way to merge the two files into one?

I call the lazyload plugin in the footer like this:

```
$("img.lazy").show();
$(window).bind("load", function() { 
    var timeout = setTimeout(function(){$("img.lazy").lazyload({effect : "fadeIn"})}, 800);
    /*$("img.lazy").show().lazyload({effect : "fadeIn"}); */
    /*$("img.lazy").lazyload({effect : "fadeIn"})*/
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to copy the source of one file into the other without any problems.

Just make sure everything is defined before you use it. A good approach is to first include jQuery, then any plugins, then your own code.

It doesn't really matter if they are in the same file or separate files - the only thing that matters is the order.

Comment: Should I paste the plugin code after my functions and my document ready declaration?

Comment: No, paste it before your code (but make sure it appears _after_ jQuery itself in your document).